# i always get this error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0"

Tags: java

```
class TriangularNumbers {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= i; j--) {
                System.out.print((i * j) + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this program, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

Comment: You don't get this error when you compile the program, but when you run it.

Comment: While you were writing your question, had you cared to glance at the suggested existing questions (now visible to the right of this page), you would have found literally *dozens* of questions almost exactly the same as this one.

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`: 0 simple solution

Answer (score 0):

You should run your program with at least a single command line argument, since it attempts to read such argument and parse it as an int (that's what `Integer.parseInt(args[0])` does).

Answer (score 0):

The args[] array seems to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

You do not give a parameter to the program. Thats why `args` is empty.

Check if the size of `args[]` is bigger than 1.

```
if (args.length<1) {
   System.out.println("No parameter");
   exit().
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should run it like `java TriangularNumbers arg0 arg1 arg2...`At least `arg0` must be present.

Answer (score 0):

You get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you try to access`args[0]` but `args` is an empty array. If you try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("my code has " + args.length + " params");
    // your code
}
```

you will see that the printed out string is `"my code has 0 params"`.

This error should disappear if you run the program with at least one argument or if you force to fill `args`, for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    args = new String[]{"10"};
    // your code
}
```

However, the inner `for-loop` you wrote will never end. Your program is an *infinite loop*. That's because it executes the cycle while `j <= i`, but at each loop `j` is decreased (`j--`). Then `j` will never be equals or greater than `i`. Your loop will never ends.